# Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, http-status-code-401

I can download
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/gallery/publishers/blueprint/extensions/vsts-open-work-items-in-excel/0.1.71/package?noPrompt=true
in my browser.
I don't need to be authenticated. it might use a cookie or something.

but the following powershell command raises error (401) Unauthorized.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/gallery/publishers/blueprint/extensions/vsts-open-work-items-in-excel/0.1.71/package?noPrompt=true"
```

how can i download it in a powershell script?

I've tried "-credential"

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/gallery/publishers/blueprint/extensions/vsts-open-work-items-in-excel/0.1.71/package?noPrompt=true" -credential "myemailaddress@yahoo.com"
```

and

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/gallery/publishers/blueprint/extensions/vsts-open-work-items-in-excel/0.1.71/package?noPrompt=true" -credential "myemailaddress@mycompany.com"
```

they ask password but none of them is working.
also i tried "-Headers"

```
$PAT = "blablabla"
$Base64PAT=[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT"))
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = ('Basic {0}' -f $Base64PAT)} 
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/gallery/publishers/blueprint/extensions/vsts-open-work-items-in-excel/0.1.71/package?noPrompt=true" -Headers $headers
```

I also tried microsoft account's username/password

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "blablabla" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "myemailaddress@yahoo.com", $securePassword

Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/gallery/publishers/blueprint/extensions/vsts-open-work-items-in-excel/0.1.71/package?noPrompt=true" -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Why don't you try to compare tcpdumps / wireshark?

Answer (score -1):

For that link you need authentication.
Find another download location without authentication. I tried it in my browser and had to authenticate. I guess your browser authenticates you through cookies.

It would not be a good idea to share that session cookie or store credentials for authentication but it might be possible to do that.

Depending on what you are trying to do Take a look at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions

The description on that page tells you to use extensions.json File that might be what you really wanted - a preset  of recommend plugins

Comment: you are right. 
It seems it needs kind of authentication but even when I signed out the download url still works in the browser.
and the powershell script with the authentication credentials still doesn't work